# Как разделить файл, но называть с цифрами

Tags: linux, файлы, split

Команда:

```
split -l 25 myfile.txt movie
```

Но она называет новые файлы буквами, а мне надо с цифрами.

Comment: `-d     use numeric suffixes starting at 0, not alphabetic` (`$ man split`)

Comment: спс, уже знаю, параметр -d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно дописать параметр -d, вот что вышло:

```
split -d -l 25 myfile.txt movie
```